# How to use search command in facebooks flowtype

Tags: flowtype

flowtype cli comes with several commands one of which is search

https://flowtype.org/docs/cli.html

as per the docs,

search:          Searches a pattern

except that I have no idea how this pattern search works.

I've tried the below option.

`flow search *`

flow: unexpected argument 'README.md', which is a file available in the directory I'm searching from.

So yeah, not really sure what I am supposed to do here.

- When I run flow type as usual, I get about a hundred errors, so something should be showing up

Comment: Marshall Roch answered the issue below, but for anyone looking to implement a search function, piping into grep works really well when you throw in the --one-line option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, that command was never fully implemented and was removed a couple of versions ago. We need to remove it from the docs.

What's happening here, though, is that your shell is expanding the * so flow is trying to run "flow search README.md other.js file.js", hence the weird message.

Comment: filed an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2306, thanks!